# How to find the application icon for nav drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-optionsmenu

I am trying to get the id for application icon so that I know when the Navigation Drawer Icon is pressed.  I know it is 16908332 because I tried logging it on

`public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`

```
03-15 20:06:39.476    .../...control.NavDrawer﹕ Menu item id: 16908332
```

I want to know how to get that id in code and does this id change when the app is installed on different devices?

I am trying to do this

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if(item.getItemId() == 16908332){ //How do I get the icon Id?
            isDrawerOpened = !isDrawerOpened;
            activity.invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        return toggleIcon.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: Found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586300/how-to-find-out-the-string-id-of-an-item-in-the-menu-knowing-its-decimal-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The home/back icon in the actionbar has the id android.R.id.home.